# How to debug shaders on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

Is there any way to debug shaders on Android (OpenGL-ES 2.0)?
I`m new to OpenGL and shaders at all, messed up something with coordinates - how do you usually solve such issues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug a GLSL shader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508818/how-to-debug-a-glsl-shader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly Max is right - there are no good tools for debuggin shaders on mobile devices, that`s why hand-made flags (change color in case of bug, etc) currently is the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this myself so I don't know how much information it gives you regarding the shaders, but it might be useful:

https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-perfhud-es