# How to debug (GLSL) shaders using Nsight?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, nvidia, nsight

How can I debug glsl shaders using Nsight?

I am using Nsight Visual Studio Edition 5.2. I've tried using Nsight Visual Studio Edition 5.1. These both don't work.  What I mean is that I've tried using this method and it doesn't work:

1. Open Visual Studio Project
2. Select "Nsight" from Menu and "Start Graphics Debugging"
3. Let the program run for a while
4. Press "Ctrl+Z"
5. Press "Space"
6. Go to "API Inspector" in Visual Studio
7. Select "Program" from left side bar
8. Select a "Source" from "Linked Shader State"
9. Place a breakpoint, exactly as I would when I debug for Visual Studio

Then after all that. The breakpoint that I've placed is icon-ed as a warning and errors this whenever I hover over it, "The breakpoint will currently be hit. Shader Debugging is not supported for this GPU"

Here is [the link](http://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition/5.2/Content/System_Requirements.htm#supported_cards) for all the supported graphics cards for Nsight Visual Studio Edition 5.2.

My graphics card is NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 970M (Notebook)

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-supported-gpus-full-list  Looks like your ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. G751JT should work.  Make sure you have the latest drivers straight from nvidia.

Comment: Yeah i have installed the latest drivers

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately:

> from: 06/22/2016
>
> Maxwell[GTX9xx] doesn’t support shader debugger, only Kepler and Fermi GPU support shader debug.

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/945730/graphics-card-for-shader-debugging-hlsl-directx11/

edit:

> Shader debugging is supported on Kepler family GPUs for Direct3D 11 and OpenGL. Direct3D 12 & Vulkan APIs and Maxwell & Pascal family GPUs will be supported in upcoming releases.

https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-features

Comment: But it says it does support !!! And who is that guy that said it ? It wasnt even from NVIDIA.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I cry . . Is there an alternative ?

Comment: Not really.   Maybe some stuff here will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508818/how-to-debug-a-glsl-shader  but nothing is going to be anything like what you want.