# Attach a running OpenGL to NSight for graphics debugging

Tags: debugging, opengl, nvidia, nsight

How do i attach a running OpenGL program to NSight for graphics debugging?
This [link](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/3.0/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Attach_CUDA_to_Process.htm) talks about how to attach a CUDA application but the same procedure is not applicable for performing graphics debugging.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Visual Studio Project
  •   Select "Nsight" from Menu and "Start Graphics Debugging"
  •   Let the program run for a while
  •   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
  •   Press <kbd>Space</kbd>
  •   Go to "API Inspector" in Visual Studio
  •   Select "Program" from left side bar
  •   Select a "Source" from "Linked Shader State"
  •   Place a breakpoint, As like you do regular debugging

also your graphics card should support debugging.

refer the below link for details.
[How to debug (GLSL) shaders using Nsight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522520/how-to-debug-glsl-shaders-using-nsight)